# How to add or modify launchers to the compiz unity dock?

Tags: unity, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity)

I'm using the natty unity compiz plugin and and I can't find a way to add, rearrange or remove launchers on the dock.